# IOS 10 setting MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 0 blanks the lock screen

Tags: ios, ios10

In iOS 7-9 you could set MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 0 to set the pause to be displayed on the lock screen. However on iOS 10 it displays only a blank screen. How to show that the player is paused on iOS 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the difference you are noticing may depend upon whether your app was actually *playing* when you locked the screen. If it was playing, then you can toggle between playing and pausing in the lock the screen and the lock screen does not go blank. You have to modify the existing now playing info, and when you pause, you have to provide the current time:

```
    let mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
    if var d = mpic.nowPlayingInfo {
        d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0
        d[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = p.currentTime
        mpic.nowPlayingInfo = d
    }
```

Here are some screen shots (from the Simulator) showing that this works.

Here's the lock screen while my app is playing:

[image]

And here's the lock screen when I tap the pause button:

[image]

You can see that it doesn't go blank.

Comment: I am using Xamarin, in general one can apply non-Xamarin specific answers to it, but in this case it seems not to be like that, I'll have to ask again and make it Xamarin specific... thanks.

Comment: But have you tested the code above on iOS 10? Because it seems to me that I am doing nearly the same on Xamarin (I keep the reference before assigning to nowPlayingInfo and then change its MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate and reassign it to the nowPlayingInfo ) and all I get is the blank screen?

Comment: After some more testing I am pretty certain it is a iOS 10 bug - I have seen that Control Center works properly and it shares info with a lock screen.

Comment: I don't think there's an iOS 10 bug here.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing this seems to be a bug in iOS - if Control Center shows info correctly and lock screen is wrong it is a system bug.

If someone knows some workaround I'll keep the question open for some time, after which I will mark this as a definite answer.

EDIT: as suggested by Matt, this is how iOS behaves and seems to be behaved before but I haven't noticed that. From my point of view it is a bug, and I am still looking for possible workaround.

Comment: I revised my answer to show screen shots to demonstrate that this does work correctly in the lock screen. I think what you are seeing is just that if you are paused when you lock the screen, you cannot _start_ again from the lock screen. But that has _always_ been true.

Comment: Yes I am asking about that. Hmmm, I haven't noted that before iOS 10, but I guess you're right. At the end of the day I think it is a bug, it shouldn't be like that. I'll upvote your answer and mark this as the answer, as I said I think this is a bug.